# Is there any way to protect again post manipulation when using AJAX to post to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I was wondering if there was any way to protect against data manipulation in AJAX posts? For example, using some sort of hash.

Comment: No – since you would have to calculate the hash (I think you mean that, not salt) client-side, everyone could see how you do it and calculate their own hash for theit own bogus data they want to send you. _Never trust any input coming from the client._

Comment: Are you wanting to protect against too many fields being supplied, or invalid values? It'll probably be easier to just validate when you do the post operation, so (a) ensure that all values are valid and would have been offered in the form, and (b) ensure that the user has access to the values they've submitted (relevant if they are supplying an ID to a restricted table).

Comment: Yes, always validate user input on the serverside !

Comment: To prevent 'man-in-the-middle' attacks? Yes, SSL. To prevent the client from falsifying data? No. You can make it *difficult*, but since the client will always have the plaintext source of your JavaScript it can still be falsified.

Comment: That isn't at all what a "salt" is...

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Anybody is free to post absolutely anything they want to your webserver. They might not even use a browser to do so. You cannot do anything outside of your server to prevent this; all you can do is authenticate your users and validate the data they're submitting.

Any solution you can invent in JavaScript will be *trivially* easy to circumvent, this is the very nature of the underlying technology. Security simply doesn't lie at the client's end of the connection, and it's [*provably impossible*](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) to push it down there.

Comment: Not entirely true `:)`. For example, a menu of primary keys (1-10) could be hashed on the server side, and supplied to the client as a list to authenticate their usage. The user wishing to inject a non-permitted value 11 could not do so, since the server has not supplied a hash for it, and the private hashing salt is not visible on the client. I agree however that such an approach is more complicated than just validating server-side - and that one should validate server-side anyway!

Comment: @halfer Not entirely true? The example you give is still *completely* server-side security, not client-side in the least. In your example, you could *drop the hashing entirely*, and just send the client the list of 10 numbers. On submission, you're still going to check that the submitted number is in your server-side list of 10 values, whether those values are hashed or not. All you've done is injected a completely meaningless, 100% redundant hashing step. Literally all the security in your scenario still exists server-side.

Comment: Well, re-reading the question, it doesn't specifically mention that the check should be done client side. I think the thrust of the question (which admittedly could be clearer) was: can hashing be used to check that data submitted is within the range of values that was supplied in the original form, without validating each one? My answer was yes, since that's a direct answer to the question, though in general doing ordinary validation is probably easier.

Comment: Additional ponderance: in writing my initial comment, I had wondered whether the OP had in mind something like a CSRF token, but for AJAX requests. This would ensure that the right data keys are submitted, perhaps allowing for key/value pairs to be injected into a table without further checks as to whether non-permitted keys are being used.

Comment: By no mean a CSRF token [that you can enforce even on AJAX requests] will ensure anything about right data keys. It will just make sure that the client performing the request is the same that fetched current page.

Comment: @halfer By that logic, you could use rot13 has your "hashing" algorithm. It's not *adding* anything, so saying you're "using" it is wrong; you're *misusing* it. As for your comment on CSRF tokens, your suggested use has *absolutely* nothing to do with what CSRF tokens are for. CSRF tokens in no way allow you to bypass "further checks" on data integrity. The whole point of CSRF tokens is that you give them out for free to anybody who requests a page; attackers get them just as easily as legitimate users.

Comment: We seem to be talking quite at cross purposes - rot13 would be replicable on the client side, and would not offer any additional security. I'm talking about hashing on the server side, with an additional secret, that an attacker cannot replicate. Yes, indeed, tokens are available to attackers too. Anyway, to take this discussion forward constructively, let us await the OP's clarifications.

Comment: (I think the OP has abandoned this question, btw - they've asked another question that appears to be a dup. I've voted to close this one, since it has insufficient detail).

Comment: @halfer You're still checking (hashed) input against a list of (hashed) values. So *why hash them*? You haven't offered any explanation for why hashing the values helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an hash for every value that the client send. Then, on your server you can check if the hash is valid, if not you discard the request.
But it seems overkill, and harder to implemente than actually checking the value your received on your server.